# Getting paths of each file of a directory into an Array in python

Tags: python, arrays, file, file-io, filepath

Im trying to put into an array `files[]` the paths of each file from the Data folder but when I try to go into subfolders I want it to be able to go down to the end of the Data file, for example I can read files in a subfolder of the main folder Data which im trying to get a list of all the paths of each file into an array but it doesn't go deeper it does not access the subfolder of the subfolder of Data without writing a loop. Want I want is a loop which has infinit depth of view of files in the Data folder so I can get all the file paths.

For example this is what I get:

`['Data/DataReader.py', 'Data/DataReader - Copy.py', 'Data/Dat/DataReader.py', 'Data/fge/er.txt']`

This is what I want but it can still go into deeper folders:

`['Data/DataReader.py', 'Data/DataReader - Copy.py', 'Data/Dat/DataReader.py', 'Data/fge/er.txt', 'Data/fge/Folder/dummy.png', 'Data/fge/Folder/AnotherFolder/data.dat']`

This is my current path, what would i need to add or change?

```
import os
from os import walk

files = []
folders = []
for (dirname, dirpath, filename) in walk('Data'):
    folders.extend(dirpath)
    files.extend(filename)
    break

filecount = 0
for i in files:
    i = 'Data/' + i
    files[filecount] = i
    filecount += 1

foldercount = 0
for i in folders:
    i = 'Data/' + i
    folders[foldercount] = i
    foldercount += 1

subfolders = []
subf_files = []
for i in folders:
    for (dirname, dirpath, filename) in walk(i):
        subfolders.extend(dirpath)
        subf_files.extend(filename)
        break

    subf_files_count = 0
    for a in subf_files:
        a = i + '/'+a
        files = files
        files.append(a)
        print files
    subf_files = []

print files
print folders
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't understand what are your trying to do, especially why you break your `walk` after the first element:

```
import os

files = []
folders = []
for (path, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk('Data'):
    folders.extend(os.path.join(path, name) for name in dirnames)
    files.extend(os.path.join(path, name) for name in filenames)

print files
print folders
```